# Check class with querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm exporting a table to CSV and I do something like this:

```
var cols = rows[i].querySelectorAll("td, th");
```

This works fine but the user can also hide/display the columns that he wants. Because I use AngularJS the hidden columns have `ng-hide`.

How could I do the `querySelectorAll` just for the non `ng-hide` columns?

Comment: `.querySelectorAll("td.ng-hide, th.ng-hide")` , pretty sure there is a more angular(y) way to do this.

Comment: but that would take take the hidden columns. If this is like css, should it work td:not(.ng-hide)?

Comment: Yeap, it does. Feel free to add my answer and I'll accept it

Comment: Ah yeah missed the 'non' in your question. You can also add the answer yourself! :)

Comment: ok, as you wish. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using CSS:

```
 .querySelectorAll("td:not(.ng-hide), th:not(.ng-hide)")
```